# How configure NServicebus V4 ConfigurarionComplete event handlers in V5?

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus4

In V4 of NServicebus there use to be an ConfigurationComplete event that we can make use of in INeedInitialization implemetation to hook up the event handlers like

```
Configure.ConfigurationComplete += () => { };
```

In V5 it looks like ConfigurationComplete is removed. I have already looked at http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgradeguides/4to5diff
and http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgradeguides/4to5#if-using-manual-references

I don't see any clear documented path for this.

Has anyone faced this? Is there any recommended way of handling this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will this help? https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/NServiceBus.Core/Config/IWantToRunWhenConfigurationIsComplete.cs

Comment: Can you describe your use case for using this? And for what scenario you were previously using this. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanFarmar IWantToRunWhenConfigurationIsComplete works! If you post you post your comment as answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [IWantToRunWhenConfigurationIsComplete](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/NServiceBus.Core/Config/IWantToRunWhenConfigurationIsComplete.cs), Will this help?